# Understanding 'Center' For RadialGradientBrushes

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I'm struggling to understand what the `Center` property does in a `RadialGradientBrush`.  The MSDN says 'Gets or sets the center of the outermost circle of the radial gradient.'  But when I set it's value, I'm getting results that don't make sense to me.

For example:

```
    <Rectangle Margin="10" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush  Center="0.5,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset=".5" />
                <GradientStop Color="DarkRed" Offset=".5" />                        
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.2" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Using the default value for 'Center' it gives me something that looks like this:

[image: Default Center Value]

Which is what I'd expect.  But if I change it to ="0.5,1" I get this:

[image: After changing center]

From the MSDN, I thought it only affected the outermost circle - which I interpreted to be the 'Black' GradientStop.  But it seems to be affecting all of them.  It gets even weirder (at least to me) if I move it further.  When I make it = "0.5,3" it ends up with something that begins to resemble a triangle.

[image]

I've done some quick searching but I haven't had much luck with an explanation that makes sense to me.  Can someone explain what Center is really doing?

Comment: Simply it keeps the radial gradient axis in center. Center "0.5,0.5" means it is in the center vertically and horizontally. "Horizontal, Vertical" ~ "0.5,0.5", so as per your scenario vertical it moved to 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brush also has a `GradientOrigin` property, also known as the "focal point". The gradient is computed for each point draw by the brush by finding that points proportional distance along the line that passes through it, between the origin and the outer circle, and using that proportional distance in a similar fashion to how shades are computed for a linear gradient brush.

In each of your examples, your origin is at the center. In the second example, the outer circle has been moved so one edge of it coincides with the origin, pushing the color at stop 0 to that edge.

The third example *is* weird, but is IMHO the natural consequence of taking an algorithm designed to place the origin *inside* the outer circle, and using it instead to fill a region where the outer circle has been shifted so far that the origin is no longer contained within in. Thus the results are mathematically correct, given the underlying algorithm, but no longer make much sense.

**<edit>**
And by "no longer make much sense", I don't mean by anyone, just that at first glance they may not.

In fact (and maybe you've already lost interest in this question…I haven't seen any follow-up or other activity from you regarding it), when you note how the point on the outer circle is selected to define the gradient line from along which the actual shade is in turn selected, the results do actually make some sense.

Inspired by the question, I threw together a quick-and-dirty program to let me easily explore different settings for `RadialGradientBrush`, and with an interactive experience, it soon became clear that the algorithm extends a ray from the origin, through the pixel to be shaded, straight to the outer circle (as I described in my first paragraph above).

There is an important caveat though: if the origin lies outside the outer circle, the point of the outer circle to which the ray extends is that which the ray approaches from the *interior* of the circle, i.e. after it's crossed into the circle from outside. It is this behavior that leads to the less-than-intuitively-obvious output.

Visually, the effect is that of looking straight down on a cone, where the base of the code is described by the outer circle (defined by the `Center`, `RadiusX`, and `RadiusY` properties) and the vertex of the cone is specified by the `GradientOrigin` property. If the origin is outside the circle, then this cone slants outward with the vertex outside the boundaries of the base, and the straight edges you see are the orthogonally projected boundaries of the cone.
**</edit>**

It is informative to look at the underlying API's documentation in such cases, and indeed it specifically calls this scenario out as "undefined". I.e. the specification does not define any specific behavior, so the algorithm is allowed to do whatever it likes (typically whatever would be most convenient, and not necessarily whatever would be most intuitively obvious). From [ID2D1RadialGradientBrush interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371529(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The brush maps the gradient stop position 0.0f of the gradient origin, and the position 1.0f is mapped to the ellipse boundary. When the gradient origin is within the ellipse, the contents of the ellipse enclose the entire [0, 1] range of the brush gradient stops. If the gradient origin is outside the bounds of the ellipse, the brush still works, **but its gradient is not well-defined**.

Indeed, it happens that at least for the current implementation, the output is "well-defined" in the sense that it's predictable and comprehensible (see edit above). But of course the behavior is not *documented*, and the implementation could be changed arbitrarily at any time. Clearly users are expected to keep the origin inside the outer circle. :)

Note also in the above that the outer circle is assumed to be where the gradient stop of 1 is located. When you specify a gradient stop greater than 1, that will lie outside the circle, and may also result in unexpected results, depending on the exact geometry.

*Note: the sample program I wrote would not be hard to recreate. But if there is interest, I am happy to include it here. I'll add it to this post if asked.*